# Unnamed parameters in C

Tags: c, gcc, macros

In C, unlike C++, all parameters to a function definition must be named.

Instead of quashing "unused parameter" errors with `(void)a`, or openly using `__attribute__((unused))`, I've created the following macro:

```
#define UNUSED2(var, uniq) UNUSED_ ## line ## var __attribute((unused))
// squash unused variable warnings, can it be done without var?
#define UNUSED(var) UNUSED2(var, __func__)
```

Used like this

```
void blah(char const *UNUSED(path)) {}
```

Is there some way I can guarantee a unique "dummy" variable name (obviously `LINE` and `__func__` can't cut it), or neglect to name the unused variables at all?

### Update0

The final code used is [available here](https://code.google.com/p/cxutil/source/browse/include/cxutil/utility.h#12).

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    // C++ allows you to omit parameter names if they're unused
#   define OMIT_PARAM
#else
    // A variable name must be provided in C, so make one up and mark it unused
#   define OMIT_PARAM3(uniq) const omitted_parameter_##uniq VARATTR_UNUSED
#   define OMIT_PARAM2(uniq) OMIT_PARAM3(uniq)
#   define OMIT_PARAM OMIT_PARAM2(__COUNTER__)
#endif

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   define VARATTR_UNUSED
#else
#   define VARATTR_UNUSED __attribute__((unused))
#endif
```

It's used like this:

```
void blah(char const *OMIT_PARAM) {}
```

And avoids both unused parameter, unnamed parameter warnings, and guarantees that it's not going to clobber some other variable name.

Comment: Broken link [2013-08-26]. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) has a `__COUNTER__` macro which gives uniqueness, it appears that GCC has an equivalent macro with the same name from version 4.3.5 (although I can't at the moment find a live link).

Comment: Well I'd like to accept this as a solution, but I have a child problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488021/unexpected-predefined-macro-behaviour-when-pasting-tokens

Answer (score 5):

Stop looking for ugly non-portable, compiler-specific hacks. Even if the function does not use one of its arguments, presumably there's a reason the argument exists: to match a particular prototype/signature, most likely for the purpose of function pointer type compatibility. Assuming this is the case, the argument **has** a name determined by what the caller is expected to pass; the fact that your particular function is not using the argument for anything is largely irrelevant. So give it its proper name, and use `__attribute__((unused))` if you insist on enabling this warning. I just always disable the unused argument warning because it's obviously bogus.