# Unexpected predefined macro behaviour when pasting tokens

Tags: c, gcc

The following (test with `gcc -E blah.c`):

```
#define UNUSED(type) type UNUSED_ ## __COUNTER__
UNUSED(char const *)
UNUSED(int)
```

Generates:

```
char const * UNUSED__COUNTER__
int UNUSED__COUNTER__
```

I'm expecting:

```
char const * UNUSED0
int UNUSED1
```

I've tried calling another macro, wrapping the arguments in brackets to no avail.
If I don't paste the tokens it seems to work fine.
The [documentation](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) specifically mentions the use of `__COUNTER__` in token pasting.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenting with gcc 4.4, this works:

```
#define UNUSED(type) UNUSED_(type, __COUNTER__)
#define UNUSED_(type, counter) UNUSED__(type, counter)
#define UNUSED__(type, counter) type UNUSED_ ## counter
UNUSED(char const *)
UNUSED(int)
```

But it doesn't work if I take out even one level of intermediates.

Answer (score 1):

`__COUNTER__` was only introduced in [GCC 4.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html) - if you happen to use an earlier version, the macro is simply not defined. In that case [Boost.PPs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) `BOOST_PP_COUNTER` macro might be worth looking into.

On newer GCC versions you still need a different approach to concatenation, as `##` prevents its arguments from expanding. Thus you have to expand them first before using `##`:

```
#define CAT(a, b) CAT_I(a, b)
#define CAT_I(a, b) CAT_II(a ## b)
#define CAT_II(x) x
#define UNUSED(type) type CAT(UNUSED_, __COUNTER__)
```

If you're already using Boost, `BOOST_PP_CAT()` gives you the same functionality.

Comment: Sorry the C++ tag was incorrect, SO changes cpp to c++... apparently someone hasn't heard of the C preprocessor

Comment: @Matt: The answer is the same for C and C++, even Boost.PP works with both.

Comment: I mean that C++isms such as Boost are not useful here. But thanks for the info.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you must "double expand" it:

```
#define STR(x)    #x
#define UNUSED(type) type UNUSED_ ## STR(__COUNTER__)
UNUSED(char const *) 
UNUSED(int)
```

Comment: No luck with this: `char const * UNUSED_STR(0)` and `int UNUSED_STR(1)`

Comment: Is space after UNUSED_ the issue?

Comment: You surely didn't mean to stringify, did you?  If this worked at all, it would produce things like `char const * UNUSED"0"`...