# How do you get the start and end addresses of a custom ELF section?

Tags: c, gcc, elf

I'm working in C on Linux. I've seen the usage of of the gcc [`__section__` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) (especially in the Linux kernel) to collect data (usually function pointers) into custom ELF sections. How is the "stuff" that gets put in those custom sections retrieved and used?

Comment: Possibly of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152018/initialize-global-array-of-function-pointers-at-either-compile-time-or-run-time/4152185#4152185

Comment: Better that an answer: http://mgalgs.github.io/2013/05/10/hacking-your-ELF-for-fun-and-profit.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As long as the section name results in a valid C variable name, `gcc` (`ld`, rather) generates two magic variables: `__start_SECTION` and `__stop_SECTION`. Those can be used to retrieve the start and end addresses of a section, like so:

```
/**
 * Assuming you've tagged some stuff earlier with:
 * __attribute((__section__("my_custom_section")))
 */

struct thing *iter = &__start_my_custom_section;

for ( ; iter < &__stop_my_custom_section; ++iter) {
    /* do something with *iter */
}
```

I couldn’t find any formal documentation for this feature, only a few obscure mailing list references. If you know where the docs are, drop a comment!

If you're using your own linker script (as the Linux kernel does) you'll have to add the magic variables yourself (see `vmlinux.lds.[Sh]` and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152018/initialize-global-array-of-function-pointers-at-either-compile-time-or-run-time/4152185#4152185)).

See [here](https://mgalgs.io/2013/05/10/hacking-your-ELF-for-fun-and-profit.html) for another example of using custom ELF sections.

Comment: You can also use Objdump -d

Comment: Note: I guessed the "valid C variable name" problem could be avoided using  `asm("__start_invalid.c.variable.name")`, but it turns out it does not work.

Comment: Dumb question: How do you make the linker put the Stop symbol at the end of the actual section, and not right after the Start symbol?

Answer (score 16):

Collecting the information together from various answers, here is a working example of how to collect information into a custom linker section and then read the information from that section using the magic variables `__start_SECTION` and `__stop_SECTION` in your C program, where `SECTION` is the name of the section in the link map.

The `__start_SECTION` and `__stop_SECTION` variables are made available by the linker so explicit `extern` references need to be created for these variables when they are used from C code.

There are also some problems if the alignment used by the compiler for calculating pointer/array offsets is different than the alignment of the objects packed in each section by the linker. One solution (used in this example) is to store only a pointer to the data in the linker section.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct thing {
    int val;
    const char* str;
    int another_val;
};
struct thing data1 = {1, "one"};
struct thing data2 = {2, "two"};

/* The following two pointers will be placed in "my_custom_section".
 * Store pointers (instead of structs) in "my_custom_section" to ensure
 * matching alignment when accessed using iterator in main(). */
struct thing *p_one __attribute__((section("my_custom_section"))) = &data1; 
struct thing *p_two __attribute__((section("my_custom_section"))) = &data2;

/* The linker automatically creates these symbols for "my_custom_section". */
extern struct thing *__start_my_custom_section;
extern struct thing *__stop_my_custom_section;

int main(void) {
    struct thing **iter = &__start_my_custom_section;
    for ( ; iter < &__stop_my_custom_section; ++iter) {
        printf("Have thing %d: '%s'\n", (*iter)->val, (*iter)->str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if the section names are not valid variable names in C

Comment: @ToddFreed Do you have an example of a section name that is not a valid variable name in C?

Comment: ".note.gnu.build-id" is not a valid variable name. This is a section created by ld when the --build-id option is specified, see https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

Comment: Dumb question: How do you make the linker put the Stop symbol at the end of the actual section, and not right after the Start symbol?

Answer (score 7):

Linker can use the symbols defined in the code, and can assign their initial values if you use the exact name in the linker script:

```
_smysection = .;
*(.mysection)
*(.mysection*)
_emysection = .;
```

Just define a variable in C code:

```
const void * _smysection;
```

And then you can access that as a regular variable.

```
u32 someVar = (u32)&_smysection;
```

Comment: This was the answer I needed. I've been using linker sections for a while now but wanted to begin sub sectioning them (e.g. `.init.subsection`). The periods in the section name prevented the linker from proceed the generic `__start/stop` labels. But just providing the labels directly in the linker script was a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer above, `__start_SECTION` and `__stop_SECTION` will work, however for the program to be able to use the information from the linker you to need to declare those variables as `extern char* __start_SECTION`. Enjoy!

```
extern char * __start_blobby;

...
printf("This section starts at %p\n", (unsigned int)&__start_blobby);
...
```

Comment: `extern <any valid type> __start_SECTION` works, I see `extern int __start_SECTION` and `extern char __start_SECTION` used the most.

Comment: @yyny in this case you need to take the address of the var e.g. `&__start_SECTION`. Otherwise you'll of course get the contents at the address and may find yourself very confused. Declaring the extern as a pointer (or array) prevents this.

Comment: I think of it the other way around. If your variable has a pointer type, you might expect the section address to be in the variable value, whereas if your variable is a `char`, its more obvious that you have to take the address. Using an array type might be a good idea, though.

Answer (score 0):

HI: like this.

```
extern const struct pseudo_ta_head __start_ta_head_section;
extern const struct pseudo_ta_head __stop_ta_head_section;    

const struct pseudo_ta_head *start = &__start_ta_head_section;
const struct pseudo_ta_head *end = &__stop_ta_head_section;
```