# Can autotools produce unlinked objects rather than a library?

Tags: c, autotools

When trying to solve the question posted here: [__start_section and __stop_section symbols missing when linking to library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669171/start-section-and-stop-section-symbols-missing-when-linking-to-library) I've determined it would be best if I could get my C autotools project to compile a list of objects without generating a library (or I can ignore the library as long as the intermediate objects are present). Here is my current Makefile.am:

```
AM_CFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/drivers/include
lib_LIBRARIES = libdriver.a
libdriver_a_SOURCES = $(STATIC_DRIVER_FILES)
STATIC_DRIVER_FILES = src/driver.c

if FLASH_SIM
STATIC_DRIVER_FILES += flash/flash_sim.c
endif

if UART_SIM
STATIC_DRIVER_FILES += uart/uart_sim.c
endif
```

This works fine and creates libdriver.a. What I need is a variable STATIC_DRIVER_OBJS that contains a list of all the compiled objects I can link to from the main application. The question posted above explains why I can't just link the the library directly.

Comment: I don't understand why what you've got (`libdriver.a`) won't work.  A `.a` library should be just a collection of `.o` files.

Comment: libdriver.a contains 2 objects. driver.c and flash_sim.c. flash_sim.c defines a bunch of static fns which are exposed via a data struct that is put in a custom ELF section. driver.c then enumerates the custom section by using the symbol __start_custom_section which get defined by the linker at link time. For whatever reason if I link directly to the object file ie: flash_sim.o the linker will create these symbols to point to that section. However if I link to the library these symbols do not get created (presumably because the struct in that section is never directly referenced).

Comment: It's very similar to how linux module init happens except they link directly to the object files (maybe for this reason). If I can get a list of object files relative to the top srcdir I should be able to accomplish the same thing using autotools. Examining the Makefile directly it looks like what I need is available in libdriver_a_OBJECTS but it isn't exported and is using relative paths...

Comment: OK, that kind of makes sense.  So `libdriver.a` is being clobbered by `ar`...

Comment: Yep, and since I'm a complete noob using autotools I can't figure out how to export a variable containing all the object files so they can be linked by another makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
whizbang_SOURCES = ... # the main executable
whizbang_LDADD = $(libdriver_a_OBJECTS) ...
```

I'd do it more like:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libdriver.la
...
libdriver_la_SOURCES = src/driver.c

if FLASH_SIM
libdriver_la_SOURCES += flash/flash_sim.c
endif
if UART_SIM
libdriver_la_SOURCES += uart/uart_sim.c
endif

...
whizbang_LDADD = $(libdriver_la_OBJECTS) ...
```

Just so you don't have to worry about dealing with `libdriver.a` (no installation).

Comment: That's what I hope to accomplish. There are 2 problems I run into:
1. The whizbang_LDADD statement is in another Makefile.am in the directory structure and $(libdriver_a_OBJECTS) doesn't appear to be visible from there (I see a .NOEXPORT at the end of the generated makefile).
2. Since it's in another spot in the directory structure I need to figure out a way to append $(top_srcdir)/subdir/ to each of the objects.
Thanks for you help!

Comment: The noinst and using libtool is a good tip. So many nice features in autotools which is why I really want to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up accomplishing this using ldav1s's answer above and converting my project to use non-recursive make. As a side effect it appears to compile faster too. Here is the guide I used to convert it to non-recursive make: https://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/automake/nonrecursive.html. It's nice to only have to maintain one Makefile.am.